# How to make this C# method generic?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

How can I make the following code generic so I can end up with a single simple function in place of multiple functions across a number of classes?

The calls to FindObject and CreateObject below are part of a 3rd party library so I have no control over the parameters to those and it is here that I am getting stuck.

```
private MyClass1 FindClass1Object( string code )
{
  MyClass1 myObject = FindObject<MyClass1>( code );

  if ( myObject == null )
  {
    myObject = CreateObject<MyClass1>( );
    myObject.Code = code;
  }

  return myObject;
}

private MyClass2 FindClass2Object( string code )
{
  MyClass2 myObject = FindObject<MyClass2 >( code );

  if ( myObject == null )
  {
    myObject = CreateObject<MyClass2 >( );
    myObject.Code = code;
  }

  return myObject;
}
```

I know that I can pass in an additional parameter to specify a type that I am looking for / creating but then the code gets stuck on the calls to FindObject and CreateObject.

```
private object ReadClassFromXml ( string code, Type myType )
{
  object myObject = FindObject<myType>( code );

  if ( myObject == null )
  {
    myObject = CreateObject<myType>( );
    myType.GetProperty("Code").SetValue(myObject, code, null);
  }

  return myObject;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make a method generic you need to add generic type definition (`<myType>`) and you don't need to use second parameter that specifies type(i.e. `Type myType` is not needed). You should also return the generic type, not `object`. I would also rename `myType` to `T`, as it is common to name generic parameters with names that start with `T`. So overall your code would look something like this:

```
// Method has generic parameter <T> and returns result of type T:
private T ReadClassFromXml<T>( string code)  
{
  object myObject = FindObject<T>( code );

  if ( myObject == null )
  {
    myObject = CreateObject<T>( );
    myType.GetProperty("Code").SetValue(myObject, code, null);
  }

  return myObject;
}
```

Keep in mind, that the generic method might require some [constraints on type parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Comment: If you threw in how to use reflection to call this method given you have a `Type myType` variable then this would be a golden answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can simple wrap up it with Generic. Simple like this one:

```
private T FindObject<T>( string code )
{
  T myObject = FindObject<T>( code );

  if ( myObject == null )
  {
    myObject = CreateObject<T>( );
    myObject.Code = code;
  }

  return myObject;
}
```

You have to implement FindObject and CreateObject too.

Comment: In your example, myObject.Code is going to throw a "Member not found" compile time exception.

Comment: You're going to recurse into oblivion there

Comment: It's really quite clear in the question that `FindObject<T>` already exists.